# I can't see my SD Card on Ubuntu

Tags: sd-card

Output of **fdisk -l**

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 217776127 216725504 103,4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  217776128 234440703  16664576     8G Linux swap
```

I can't see my SD Card here.

and results of **dmesg**

```
[ 1955.386420] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 62333952 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.7 GiB)
[ 1955.394418] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.394424] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.394428] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.394432] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.394434] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.394438] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.395907] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.395920] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.395925] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.395928] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.395930] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.395932] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.397404] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.397417] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.397420] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.397422] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.397424] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.397426] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.397462] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1955.398927] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.398939] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.398942] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.398944] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.398946] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.398948] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.400383] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.400386] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.400389] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.400392] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.400393] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.400395] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.401882] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.401886] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.401888] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.401900] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.401902] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.401904] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.403383] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.403386] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.403389] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.403401] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.403402] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.403404] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.403439] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1955.404884] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.404887] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.404890] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.404901] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.404903] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.404905] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.406383] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.406386] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.406388] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.406400] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.406402] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1955.406404] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1955.407899] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1955.407902] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1955.407905] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1955.407907] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1955.407909] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1955.407911] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 1955.410974]  sdb: unable to read partition table
```

I use an adapter for my desktop PC. I can see my images in my Nikon camera but can't reach them with computer.

Comment: Looks like a damaged SD card or SD card reader. Have you tried plugging your Nikon into the computer using a USB cable? You may be able to transfer photos using the camera's file transfer protocol.

Comment: RoboKaren, thanks for your advice! I used my USB cable to transfer photos and now I can format my SD Card :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a damaged SD card or SD card reader. Have you tried plugging your Nikon into the computer using a USB cable? You should be able to transfer photos using the camera's built-in file transfer protocol.